# Location of cognos sdk in cognos installation folder

Tags: sdk, cognos

As per this article, 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/development/how_to/page565.html#download

the Cognos SDK for cognos 8 is located in folder:`<cognos-directory>/sdk` 
This directory is not present in cognos 10. So where is the SDK component located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK is a separate component and must be downloaded and installed in addition to an existing Cognos product install.  When you add it to an existing Cognos 10 installation it will create and unpack to an SDK folder under the root of the install.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to this, in case anyone finds this via search.

The SDK is now included with Cognos 11.1.X server installs. Up to this version, including 11.0.X, the SDK was a separate install.

And, the SDK works best when installed alongside the server. We have found it easier to develop using remote SSH via Visual Studio Code or running Eclipse remotely on our development Cognos servers. Both work well, and you only need to install and configure it server-side. All of your devs can then work with the one instance. If remote isn't possible, dev's will need to install and configure a local Cognos Server.